# Update and delete buttons C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-delete

I wrote the code for the update button and the delete button.
My purpose is update and delete the datas that I've inserted into the database (that was created in mysql with phpmyadmin).

Update button code:

```
void ModificaBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Connessione.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter SDA=new MySqlDataAdapter("UPDATE INTO GARA set nome_gara='"+textBox1.Text+"',giudice='"+textBox2.Text+"',località='"+textBox3.Text+"',data='"+textBox4.Text+"',tpsopm='"+textBox5.Text+"',tpmopm='"+textBox6.Text+"',tpstot='"+textBox7+"',tpmtot='"+textBox8.Text+"')VALUES'"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"','"+textBox3.Text+"','"+textBox4.Text+"','"+textBox5.Text+"','"+textBox6.Text+"','"+textBox7.Text+"','"+textBox8.Text+"')",Connessione);
        SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Connessione.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Dati modificati correttamente!");

    }
```

Delete button code:

```
void CancellaBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Connessione.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter SDA=new MySqlDataAdapter("DELETE FROM GARA(nome_gara,giudice,località,data,tpsopm,tpmopm,tpstot,tpmtot)VALUES'"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"','"+textBox3.Text+"','"+textBox4.Text+"','"+textBox5.Text+"','"+textBox6.Text+"','"+textBox7.Text+"','"+textBox8.Text+"')",Connessione);
        SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Connessione.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Dati cancellati correttamente!");
    }
```

I haven't syntax error, but when I run the program and I try to modify or delete the data, the compiler show me an unhandled exception (An Unhandled exception of type MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException was thrown). When I quit the window this line is selected `SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`

I use the same instruction for the insert button, but it works.

Can you help me, please?

**Edit:** I've tried your solutions, but the values don't update into the db. I can modify them into the dataGridView, but when I press the update button they don't change

Comment: Syntax is incorrect, `DELETE FROM GARA WHERE ID=@ID`, you have `DELETE FROM GARA(Columns...)`. Also use sql-parameters instead of string concatenation if you want to keep your database. Otherwise your open for sql injection. Apart from that, use `MySqlCommand` directly instead of `MySqlDataAdapter`.

Comment: The inner exception should provide you with more specific information

Comment: You should work with parameters. Do NEVER concatenate the values into your queries. Read up on SQL injection

Comment: Consider learning about SQL first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update don't need  INTO  but  only

```
UPDATE   GARA 
 SET set nome_gara='"+textBox1.Text+"'
,giudice='"+textBox2.Text+"'
,località='"+textBox3.Text+"'
,.....
```

eventulally add where condition  for update the rows you need

Delete don't need  value  you delete the rows  with match where  condition  eg:

```
DELETE FROM GARA
WHERE nome_gara='"+textBox1.Text+"'"
```

be sure for the proper where condition

and be careful in string concat that you are at risk for sql injections

Comment: `SQL Injection` ... do consider it always.

Comment: @Rahul   correct  .. answer  updated  with this recccomantion too

Comment: @scaisEdge How about showing how to do it instead of recommending to do it? The OP is obviously new, so how should he implement your recommendation?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar  correct but    i have  just  a biref suggestion for sql injection   because seems that actually the main problem  is the basic SQL sintax .. i thinks that this is the firts .. suggestion to do at this new OP  .. but if you want you can add  some link with proper (and useful ) indicatio for this  ..

Answer (score 2):

I don't mean to sound harsh, but your code is not very good. Points to improve:

1. Use correct SQL
2. Stop using `MySqlDataAdapter` when you don't need to
3. Use paramterized queries to avoid SQL injections (and no: there's no excuse whatsoever for not doing this!)

These three points will lead to the following code:

```
void ModificaBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Connessione.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE GARA set nome_gara=@nomegara,giudice=@giudice,località=@localita,data=@data ...",Connessione);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomegara", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@giudice", textBox2.Text);
    ...

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("Dati modificati correttamente!");
}

void CancellaBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Connessione.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd =new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM GARA WHERE Field = @value, ...",Connessione);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", ...);
    ...

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Dati cancellati correttamente!");
}
```

Comment: I know my code is far to be perfect. I'm a beginner, I still have a lot to learn. Thank you for the advices

Comment: I know, I can tell from your code :-) I just said it to show how urgent it is for you to change the code.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but I have the same problem with the ExecuteNonQuery(). Any ideas?

Comment: Yes. We know. But what's the underlying error message?

Comment: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Fatal error encountered during command execution. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Parameter '@localita' must be defined.

Then there are a long list of other errors. 
I defined the parameter 'località', indeed with the insert I have no problems.

Comment: Well, yes, you need to a) define all required parameters in the SQL String and b) you need one `AddParameterWithValue` call for each parameter. You can **not** simply copy above code and run it. It will not work, because as you can easily see I shortened it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128942/discussion-between-matteo-and-thorsten-dittmar).